# What is the equivalent to __OPTIMIZE__ in visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

In GCC we have the macro `__OPTIMIZE__` defined when the compiler is set to optimise code. Is there an equivalent macro in Visual studio ?

Comment: Looking at MSDN there doesn't seem to be an equivalent. You can test for `#ifdef NDEBUG`, but that doesn't necessarily mean optimisations are enabled.

Comment: Since this doesn't seem to be available I reported an enhancement bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1065645

Answer (score -5):

In your solution, right click your project and select: `Properties`. Now you see your project properties window. Select the drop-down menu named: `C/C++`. There should be a sub-menu: `Optimizations`. I just checked both 2010 and 2013, it is all in place. There you have the options of selecting what specific optimizations you want.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to improve your answer. As it stands, this is merely a comment.

Comment: You misunderstood the question, the OP is not asking how to activate optimizations, but how to detect whether optimizations are activated from within the code.